# How to check if a list contains specific class in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Several classes inherit from abstract class `Illness` and overrides a field `name`
Illness.cs:

```
namespace health;
abstract class Illness{
    public abstract string name { get;}
}

class Cancer : Illness{
    public override string name { 
        get{ return "Cancer";}
    }
}

class Covid : Illness{
    public override string name { 
        get{ return "Covid";}
    }
}
```

There is an empty list `List<Illness> illnesses = new List<Illness>` in main class and the goal is to make a method, which adds a value to `illnesses` list only if this list doesn't contain the given class already.
Tried to do this:

```
public void addIllness(Illness illness){
        if (!illnesses.Contains(illness)){
            illnesses.Add(illness);
        }
    }
```

but not working.

Comment: `if (!illnesses.Any(x=>x is Covid))`

Comment: @LeiYang `if(!illnesses.Any(x=>x is typeof(illness))` - add if illness already present, not just Covid

Comment: Are there any performance requirements? How fast this check should be done? What is estimated number of items in list?

Comment: i realized that the OP is wondering how to compare instance(need implement `IEquatable`, or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`), not check type.

Comment: Are you trying to build an enum using classes?

Comment: List length can be maximum 5 or8

Comment: I want to check if list already contains given type of illness type

Comment: @Ksardas21: so, use the code from the 1st comment.

Comment: @Dennis first comment check if its Covid, not if the illness already exists (I assume other derived  classes will exist)

Comment: Do you want to support creating multiple instances of `Covid`? If not, why make the constructor public at all? Do you actually want to create singletons? Maybe something similar to the way java defines enums. Like `static Illness Covid = new Illness("Covid-19");` Because then `==` will work with just reference comparisons.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify something, I have several classes which inherit from illness, Covid was just an example,

Comment: But are they *all* singletons? eg only one instance of each can ever be created.

Comment: non of them are singletons

Comment: Sure, none of them are singletons *now*. What I'm suggesting is that you should make them all singletons. So that it is "impossible" for any part of your code to create 2 of them. So you don't need to worry about equality of types, since you can rely on equality of references. Ask yourself this question, "If a user creates two instances of Covid, would they be different in anyway?" if the answer is "No", then you should create a single instance, and make the constructor private to prevent any others.

Comment: I am kinda making enum out of classes, I don't want to add any static or singleton classes in this project right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Property uniqueness

If you are using `Illness.Name` to specify something special about the illness, like the type of cancer og covid infection. Then you would like to check name of the illness before adding it to the list of illnesses:

```
public abstract class Illness
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class Cancer : Illness
{
    public Cancer(string cancerName)
    {
        Name = cancerName;
    }

    public override string Name { get; }
}

public class Covid : Illness
{
    public Covid(string covidName)
    {
        Name = covidName;
    }

    public override string Name { get; }
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        AddIllness(new Cancer("Breast Cancer"));
        AddIllness(new Cancer("Breast Cancer"));
        AddIllness(new Cancer("Lung Cancer"));
        AddIllness(new Covid("SARS-CoV-1"));
        AddIllness(new Covid("SARS-CoV-2"));
        AddIllness(new Covid("SARS-CoV-2"));
    }

    public List<Illness> Illnesses { get; } = new();

    public void AddIllness(Illness illness)
    {
        if (Illnesses.All(i => i.Name != illness.Name))
        {
            Illnesses.Add(illness);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example you'll see that the list of illnesses would only contain 4 items after the Main constructor has been initialized.

## Class uniqueness

If you are using the class type as uniqueness criteria you would like to check against all the class types that already exists in the list `Illnesses` before you would add the `Illness`

```
public abstract class Illness
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

public class Cancer : Illness
{
    public override string Name => "Cancer";
}

public class Covid : Illness
{
    public override string Name => "Covid-19";
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        AddIllness(new Cancer());
        AddIllness(new Cancer());
        AddIllness(new Covid());
        AddIllness(new Covid());
    }


    public List<Illness> Illnesses { get; } = new();

    public void AddIllness(Illness illness)
    {
        if (Illnesses.All(i => i.GetType() != illness.GetType()))
        {
            Illnesses.Add(illness);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example you'll see that the list of illnesses would only contain 2 items after the Main constructor has been initialized.

#### Overriding EqualityComparer

Another way is to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method. Then you would be able to use `Contains` as in your example.

```
public abstract class Illness
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        return GetType() == obj.GetType();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return GetType().GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Cancer : Illness
{
    public override string Name => "Cancer";
}

public class Covid : Illness
{
    public override string Name => "Covid-19";
}

public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        AddIllness(new Cancer());
        AddIllness(new Cancer());
        AddIllness(new Covid());
        AddIllness(new Covid());
    }


    public List<Illness> Illnesses { get; } = new();

    public void AddIllness(Illness illness)
    {
        if (!Illnesses.Contains(illness))
        {
            Illnesses.Add(illness);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example you'll see that the list of illnesses would only contain 2 items after the Main constructor has been initialized.

Even if you are doing it this way, you could also change `Illnesses` to be a `HashSet<Illness>` that will automatically check whether the class already exists in the set.

```
public class Main
{
    public Main()
    {
        Illnesses.Add(new Cancer());
        Illnesses.Add(new Cancer());
        Illnesses.Add(new Covid());
        Illnesses.Add(new Covid());
    }

    public HashSet<Illness> Illnesses { get; } = new();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can (as mentioned by [Lei Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1518100/lei-yang)) solve this by checking he type:

- `if(!illnesses.Any(i=>i is typeof(Covid)){ ... }` for a specific type.
- `if (!illnesses.Any(i => i.GetType() == illness.GetType())) { ... }` comparing the type of the objects.

You could also create a generic method to achieve this in a nice manner:

```
public void Add<T>(T illness) where T : Illness{
    if(!illnesses.Any(t=>t is T)){
        illnesses.Add(illness);
    }
}
```

As you are overriding `name` you could even use that for better performance:

`if(!illnesses.Any(i=>i.name == illness.name)){ ... }`
This is however more or less the explicit version of what (again) @Lei Yang proposed in implementing `IEquatable`.

This however seems to be a bit strange of an approach, you should use objects when you can have more than one instance of a class, else maybe reconsider adding a "IllnessType" enum beside the Name and ditch the inheritance.

Comment: worked using `if(!illnesses.Any(i=>i.name == illness.name))`,
besides, I get `'illness' is a variable but is used like a type [classes and structs]csharp(CS0118)` while using `if(!illnesses.Any(i=>i is typeof(illness))`

Comment: ah, true, sorry for that, will adapt. the answer created by @Jogge however seems to be much more into depth anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can check class using **GetType** method.

```
if (!illnesses.Any(i => i.GetType() == illness.GetType()))
{
   illnesses.Add(illness);
}
```

Comment: Works, and suits the question title better